# Naive approach to estimate or calculate the visual difference between characters

Tags: algorithm, graphics, fonts, difference

My starting point was to generate random passwords that are visually easy to recognize. I first decided to omit characters that will be **probably visually indistinguishable** from the set I choose from randomly. Maybe this is a nonsense idea, because random passwords will be copy-pasted most time. I'm also aware that the difference between two given chars depends on the font, but since every-day fonts are designed to be read by humans, there will be some font-independent characteristics.

Some examples of character pairs that have a low distance from each other in most fonts:

- O 0
- 1 l
- 5 S

Is there an easy way to "calculate" this sort of distances? 
What is the name of this computational discipline, that I can be googled?

---

Edit: I now found that the term is **Homoglyph**

Comment: This specific problem has already been solved, there are several well-known sets of characters chosen to be easily distinguishable. Windows licence keys, for example.

Comment: @delnan Thanks. but It's not my intent to create a font, I know that there are many of it for instance the [FE-Schrift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FE-Schrift)

Comment: a naive idea : XOR the pixels (white: 0, black: 1) and count the total of resulting 0.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you create a new font, or use an existing special-purpose font. I'm speaking of *sets of characters* optimized for all characters being easily distinguishable in some (often several common) fonts.

Comment: @Michael interesting, but I'll have to normalize the glyphs first, maybe match the top-left pixel.

Comment: @delnan seems I'm getting what you are talking of, do you have a link at hand?

Comment: Unfortunately no link. Just heard off-hand comments about it.

Comment: Here's the top result when Googling "set of distinguishable characters": https://github.com/komola/distinguishable . If you're still looking to do it yourself independently I do have a couple of ideas I can leave in an answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks for the link. If I look on the resulting `CDEHKMPRSTUWXY012458` - I'm really getting curious what I'd find... ...but on the other hand, the examples `rn, m` and `vv, w` were something I probably would have completely forgotten. If you have the time for an answer, it would be nice to see some of your ideas.